# UISearchController searchBar disappears on first click

Tags: ios, tableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented a UISearchController in a TableView, pushed by a Navigation Controller.

First my problem was that whenever I click on the SearchBar, it disappears. It works when I enter some text, but it stays completely blank. Then I managed to semi solve the issue using this code:

```
- (void)searchForText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    [self.view addSubview:villeSearchController.searchBar];
}
```

Which semi-works because now, when I click on the search bar, it blanks out, but if I enter one character, it appears again, and then it stays there, no matter what. Until I cancel the search, and click on it again, in that case it blanks out.
I have made some tests and this method (searchForText) is called on the very first click, so that isn't the reason.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue and make the searchbar appear from the very first click?

EDIT:

This is how I initialize the SearchController:

```
villeSearchController = [[UISearchController alloc]   initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
villeSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
villeSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
villeSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
villeTableView.tableHeaderView = villeSearchController.searchBar;
villeSearchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[villeSearchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Hi. Please show your code for initialization of `uisearchcontroller`. Check this link and ensure that your initialization code is properly. [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code. It looks fine to me

Comment: 1) Try to check the `NavigationBar` a translucent property - it should be `YES` when `SearchController` will present the `searchBar` or else will be UI bugs.
2) If `UISearchController` used a default presentation you should not manually manage to adding `searchBar` to subView.

Comment: Your first option works for me ! Please put it as an answer and I will accept it. The first option combined with the second! I don't add the subview anymore and just put the transluscent property!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to check the `navigationBar.translucent` property - it should be YES when `UISearchController` will present the `searchBar` or else will be UI bugs.

*Update from @SiavA*

The better solution is use the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` property of the `UIViewController`. If you using the opaque navigation bar just set it in the `true` for controller which will be show `UISearchController` (not for `navigationController`).

E.g.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = !self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent;
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!

Comment: It's not UI bug. If navigationBar.transcluent is NO, then your navigation bar is opaque and u have to notify UI about it corresponding to iOS 7 Using View Controllers (also take a look at edgesForExtendedLayout): 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html
So, to fix your "bug" u have to set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars to YES for your navigation controller.

Comment: @SiavA. Hi. A nice comment. I will add it to the response.

Answer (score 24):

This happened to me when the `UISearchController` was hiding the navigation bar.  Setting this property fixed it:

`UISearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;`

Comment: Thanks mate.. Saved my day..!! Cheers

Comment: This is the correct answer. It even works for iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

Place the SearchController inside a UIScrollView and it will work fine. This if you are using it in the section header or as a separate view

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem in iOS11 (and especially if it worked pre iOS11), I had to change my UISearchController to be attached to the navigationItem rather than the tableView.

After setting parameters on my searchController, I used to do this:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Now I have this:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

The "translucent" fix would allow the controller to appear, but when I would try and unwind to a specific segue, I'd get a crash. Attaching the searchController to the navigationItem fixed both the display and the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Setting isHidden of the navigation bar to false stopped the search bar from disappearing for me.

```
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys there is a very simple solution for the issue.
-- this will solve major issues with collections of views and a parent view containing multiple viewcontrollers.

- you don't need any below code if you have just remove it from your code

`// searchController.definesPresentationContext = true`

`// self.definesPresentationContext = true`

`// self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars =  !(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent)!`

I just add below code make sure you set searchController always set nil
if you are switching between viewControllers there may be some conflicts that can be cleared by setting it searchController nil in the `setupsearchbar()`.
also, disable the searchController on viewDidDissapear(), it will solve the issue related to active search bar moving on to the next screen.

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


func setupSearchBar() {

 searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

// adding search controller
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

// changing font color when user types
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .black

//allows select results from filtered table
searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)

searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
 
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
 
    
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    searchController.isActive = false

}
```